# How to load data set having multiple 'No-extension files' in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to load a dataset for my machine learning project and it requires me to load files having no extensions.
I tried :

```
import os
import glob
files = filter(os.path.isfile, glob.glob("./[0-9]*"))
for name in files:
    with open(name) as fh:
        contents = fh.read()
```

But doesn't return anything, mainly that glob command has nothing in it.
Also tried :

```
import os
import glob

path = './dataset1/training_validation/2012-07-10/'
for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*')):
    print("test")
    file = open(infile, 'r')
    print(file)
```

but this returns [] because of that glob command.

I'm stuck in here and couldn't find anything over the internet.

My actual problem is to load 'no extension files in a training and testing set' from two folders, validation, and the test itself. I can iterate through the folder but don't know how to handle those file types.

When I open those files in a text editor. it shows me something like this.

[image]

So I know that it's a binary format of an image, but have no idea how can I store and train them.

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. File extensions (.txt , .dat , .bat, .f90, etc.) are not meaningful to python, at least when using `glob` or `numpy` or something of the sort, because it's just part of a string. Some of us are raised (within Windows) to believe that file extensions mean something (I too fell for it).
2. The file you are looking at is a text file, containing the ASCII representation of a binary image on 0's and 1's. So, it's not a binary file, and it's not an image file (per-se), but it is a text file, which means we can read it as such from python.

To read this in, you could do either:
1. Use `numpy` to do `data = numpy.loadtxt(<filename>)`, however you might have trouble delimiting the digits.
2. Use Python's standard `open` function on the file, and loop through each line using `for line in <file_handle>:`. This way, each row of data is a string, which can be parsed easily (see documentation on string indexing). 
Good luck!

Comment: that worked well, thanks. but i'm now getting an output as array([1.11000000e+22, 1.00111100e+26, .... something like this. isn't it possible to get exact data?

Comment: It looks like `loadtxt` is reading each row as a single large float. This makes sense since there are no delimiters between digits. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

IMO this simply means that your `path` does not exist.

Perhaps you try in a first test an absolute path to your folder, as you eventually confused the relative position of the folder to your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the following code.

```
 fileNames = [f for f in listdir(dirName) if isfile(join(dirName, f))]
 random.shuffle(fileNames)
 for files in fileNames:
 data = open(dirName+'/'+files,'r');
```

Thanks for your responses.